# issue on formulas applied to date/time excel

Tags: excel

I have an issue which is blocking for me actually. 
i have a file which allows to : 
-write a departure time (date/hour/minute) and an arrival time (date/hour/minute)
- calculate the gap between the two (and give a result  : day/hour/minutes - this work

but now i want to work on the gap result that i obtained
i want to calculate the average/ the minimum/maximum 
and when i use the formulas, nothing is working !!
any idea on how to solve it ? 
per formulas or macros ...
i want to work on this (pictures) actually cells are in format "hour"

[image: the part i want to work on]

thanks for you help

Comment: Post the formula that you are using to create the time difference.

Comment: hi im using this...=ENT(D7-A7)&" jours "&TEXTE(MOD(D7-A7;1);"[hh]:mm")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot looks as if the formula returns text, which cannot be summed or averaged. Instead of returning text, just return a number. You can use formatting to show the number in the desired manner, but the underlying value can still be used for calculations.

The screenshot shows that the formula in column C calculates just the number. The custom format used to display the number is

`d jou\r\s hh:mm`

The formulas in column E average and sum the values in column C and are formatted with the same custom format.

[image]

Comment: =ENT(D7-A7)&" jours "&TEXTE(MOD(D7-A7;1);"[hh]:mm")

Comment: I added a suggestion